# Name dynamic columns plsql plsql (pivot)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, pivot

How can I create the names of a column with the name of a variable, is it possible?

```
SELECT '05/07/2019' as sysdate
  FROM dual
```

The problem is when I'm going to do the pivot I have rows

```
PRODUCT | VALUE
:------ | ----:
Shirts  |  1200
tax     |    15
Stocks  |   500
tax     |    20

SELECT *
FROM   test_data
PIVOT ( SUM( value ) FOR product IN (
  'Shirts'  AS Shirts, -- Estos nombres se generan dinamicamente con una LISTAGG
  'tax'     AS tax,
  'Stocks'  AS Stocks,
  'tax'     AS tax
) ) p
```

Error : `ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined`

It is clear that it is because of the value of the taxes, what I want to get is the following:

```
SHIRTS | tax (Shirts) | STOCKS | tax (Stocks)
-----: | -----------: | -----: | -----------:
  1200 |           35 |    500 |           35
```

Please keep in mind that the columns of the pivot I am building dynamically, therefore I could not give them the manual name, because the registers are dynamic

Comment: Any chance  `test_data` has any row ordering column (ID, DateTime , etc) ?

Comment: @Gdaimon When viewing a table with rows that simply are named as 'tax', how do you know what that row is referring to?  As in... how do you know what tax that row is based on whether it is Shirt Tax or Stocks tax or other?  Is the tax row simply based on the row that precedes it based on some sort of ordering?

Comment: There is nothing in your posted source table which allows you to sort the `'Tax'` rows. Without a meaningful key there is no way to deliver the outcome you want.

Comment: @APC Excuse me, you are absolutely right, if you have an id with which you can join, but this is the result after joining them, you parce well if I put the origin of the data, to make the question clearer ...?

Comment: @Serg if you have an id with which you can join, but this is the result after joining and filtering, it seems good if I put the origin of the data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution below assumes you have a way to order the data appropriately and that each row found to have the text **tax** in the product column is the tax based on the preceding row.  The solution uses LAG and then creates the unique new column names using concatenation based on the product of the preceding row.

```
WITH test_data AS
(
  --PRODUCT | VALUE
  --:------ | ----:
  SELECT 1 AS ord, 'Shirts' AS product, 1200 AS value FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS ord, 'tax',      15            FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS ord, 'Stocks',   500           FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 4 AS ord, 'tax',      20            FROM dual
)

--SELECT * FROM   test_data

, test_data_extended AS
(
  SELECT product, value, LAG(product, 1) OVER (ORDER BY ord) AS pre_product
  FROM test_data
)

, test_data_new AS
(
  SELECT product AS old_product, value
    /* If ordering is available you can rename the field before the PIVOT to make the new PIVOT column Unique */
    , CASE WHEN product = 'tax' THEN 'tax (' || pre_product || ')' ELSE product END AS new_product
  FROM test_data_extended
)

, new_data AS
(
  SELECT new_product, value
  FROM test_data_new
)

SELECT * FROM new_data
PIVOT 
( 
  SUM( value )
  FOR new_product IN 
  (
    'Shirts'       AS "Shirts",
    'tax (Shirts)' AS "tax (Shirts)",
    'Stocks'       AS "Stocks",
    'tax (Stocks)' AS "tax (Stocks)"
  )
) 
;
```

[image]